# CSS background-position combined types

Tags: css, background-position

CSS3 background customize is a powerful tool, but it lacks one feature for me. I can set *background-position* in few ways, but I need some combinations of those. For example, there is a dynamically re-sized div, and I need a right-center oriented image which is 15px from the right border. I can not find any way to handle this.
I could use two fixes, none of them are elegant.
1. I leave a blank 15px area on the picure's right side.
2. I use this: **background-position: 97% 50%**
But, in the second case, if the div is re-sized, the calculated right margin will be incorrect.
Or, I use a standard image instead of bg-image, but I try to avoid this.
So, is there any solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you still need the text in the div to go all the way to the right? Or can it be 15px from the right as well?

Comment: The text inside the div is aligned to the left. And, of course the text can't go over the img, so I need to put a right-padding.

Comment: "And, of course the text can't go over the img." Well that is pretty much the opposite of what `background-image` is used for XD. If you want the image to be a physical entity with no text on top I would go with using an img tag, I could put something together of that nature for you.

Comment: I know, this is quite away from practical usage, I'm just interested in this. The advantage of this method could be that the image doesn't appear in the DOM directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 extends `background-position` to allow for that. For example, you can do:

```
background-position: right 15px bottom 15px;
```

Unfortunately, only Opera currently supports this.

However, the common reason you want that, is that you have a 15px padding. If that's the case, you can just do:

```
background-origin: content-box;
background-position: right bottom;
```

which is supported by every CSS3 browser.

Comment: This is absolutely what i am looking for! The case is as you described, the padding now moves the image from the border. Thanks!